# Truncate feeds in getStream

Tags: getstream-io

I would like to limit the number of feed updates (records) in my GetStream app. I want to keep each feed at a constant length of 500 items.

I make heavy use of the 'to:' field, which results in a lot of feeds of different lengths. I want them all to grow to 500 items, so I would rather not remove items by date.

For what it's worth, I store all the updates in my own database which results in a replica of the network activity.

What would be a good way of keeping my feeds short?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no straightforward way to limit your feeds to 500 items. There's 2 ways to remove activities from Stream:

- the `removeActivity` method, which will remove 1 activity at a time via the `foreign_id` or activity id (https://getstream.io/docs/js/#removing-activities)
- the "Truncate Data" button on the dashboard for your app, which will remove all activities in Stream.

It *might* be possible to get the behavior you're looking for by keeping track of *all* activities that you're adding to Stream, then periodically culling the ones that put you over 500.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: No straightforward way.. well, I guess that's the answer. Thanks!
Since I know about all my feeds, I think I will check each one regularly and remove excess items.

Comment: As an aside, "Truncate data" is a bit of a misnomer. I would call it "Clear data" to show that it removes all data, and does not only cut off or shorten, which to me is the meaning of truncate. Another thing, "Truncate Data" not only removes the activities but all follow relationships. OK, it's data, but I wasn't expecting that. Since feeds don't really exist without activities or follow relationships, "Truncate" really means "Start Over"!